# How to concatenate and format date and time to timestamp/datetime in Intersystems Caché database

Tags: intersystems-cache, intersystems-iris

Utilizing the Intersystems Cache documentation and my limited SQL knowledge, I have figured out that Cache has it's own internal way to turn datetime into a six digit integer, but I can't figure out how to get it back to a human understandable format (the Intersystems documentation on how to do this is not comprehensible to me). I have a date column in yyyy-mm-dd, and a text time column in hh:ss xm, and I'm working in DBeaver. I need one column in datetime or datetime2.

```
SELECT appointment_date, CAST(appointment_start_time as TIME) ast,
       appointment_date + appointment_start_time as sdt
FROM foobar
```

Example:

```
appointment_date   ast          sdt

2016-09-21         14:30:00     64184
```

Desired outcome:

```
appointment_date   ast          sdt

2016-09-21         14:30:00     2016-09-21 14:30:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [CAST](https://docs.intersystems.com/irislatest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RSQL_cast) or [CONVERT](https://docs.intersystems.com/irislatest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RSQL_convert), and instead of '+', use [STRING](https://docs.intersystems.com/irislatest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RSQL_string) for concatenation

```
STRING(CAST(appointment_date as VARCHAR) , ' ' , appointment_start_time)
STRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR,appointment_date,105), ' ' , appointment_start_time)
```

105 is for format dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: Thanks. I was then able to convert to timestamp: 

{fn CONVERT(STRING(CAST(appointment_date as VARCHAR) , ' ' , appointment_start_time), SQL_TIMESTAMP)}